# PHP PDO SQL query not finding IS NOT NULL rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, null

```
table
-----
id column1
1  some random text
2  more random text
3  
4  blah blah
5
6
7
8
9

$sqlData7 = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id, column1 FROM table WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL");
$rowTotal7 = $sqlData7->rowCount();
$attIdArr7 = $sqlData7->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

print_r($attIdArr7);
```

This should return:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 4 )
```

but is returning

```
Array ( )
```

What am I doing wrong that it is not picking up the not null columns?

I don't think I need an additional boolian column "is_column1_Null" that I can query but after half a day trying to get this to work I am about to add it.

many thanks

Comment: That's a fishy question as a demo below clearly demonstrates that the current query actually **works**

Comment: Why should it return that? As far as I see, you didn't execute the query

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `$sqlData7->execute()`

```
<?php
$sqlData7 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, column1 FROM `table` WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL");
$sqlData7->execute();
$rowTotal7 = $sqlData7->rowCount();
$attIdArr7 = $sqlData7->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 1);

var_dump($attIdArr7);
```

[PHP PDO Online test](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/d892739fdbc3f20679800dd5229e8890/php/php8/15d0e6f86e2a011a7cab5394b8f7a211/)

Comment: It had SQL execute I just forgot to add it into the example code. The issue was with the actual  PDO SQL query which was why it was returning an empty array. The solution that worked was provided by Suryapal Rao.

Answer (score 0):

You can do write the following query to get the expected result

```
SELECT id, column1 FROM table column1 IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(column1) <> '';
```

The above database design suggest that the column is empty and not set to null but can be null also. So I check for two conditions, check if the column is not null and also to check whether it's not empty. I think it's inserting data without any validation, so it's insert empty values too.

Comment: Huge thanks. That solved it.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?

Comment: Sorry, thank you for reminding me to explain the situation of correcting the data. @NicoHaase

Comment: It doesn't answer the question why SQL query is not finding rows that are NOT NULL. You misunderstood the question and your answer is wrong.